# Create monthly pandas DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, datetimeindex

I have a dataframe with 12 values that I want to convert to DatetimeIndex type

```
months = df['date'] #e.g. '2016-04-01'
idx = pd.date_range(months[0], months[11], freq='M')
```

However, the resulting DatetimeIndex length is only 11, which should be 12
Not sure if is it because of the freq, which shifts date to the month end?

Comment: Can you add your all column `date` and desired output to your question? Are values sorted in column `date`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me work generating with `periods`:

```
print df
         date
0  2016-01-01
1  2016-02-01
2  2016-03-01
3  2016-04-02

print pd.date_range(df['date'].iloc[0], periods=12, freq='M')
DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-31', '2016-02-29', '2016-03-31', '2016-04-30',
               '2016-05-31', '2016-06-30', '2016-07-31', '2016-08-31',
               '2016-09-30', '2016-10-31', '2016-11-30', '2016-12-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')
```

Why last value is missing - [check in the end](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#generating-ranges-of-timestamps):

```
months = df['date'] 
print pd.date_range(months.iloc[0], months.iloc[3], freq='M')
DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-31', '2016-02-29', '2016-03-31'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')
```

> The start and end dates are strictly inclusive. So it will not generate any dates outside of those dates if specified.